# Is there Liferay API access to the tagsentries_tagsassets table?

Tags: tags, liferay, portlet

I'm working on a portlet for one of our users who want migrate a load of data from one Liferay instance to another (and LAR files are failing to generate). One of the items of data that needs to be moved is the Tags associated with the Journal Articles.

So I can access the tags themselves through the TagsEntryLocalServiceUtil class, but I can't access the tagsassets_tagsentries table through any method or class (that I can find so far). Is there a service that accesses this table directly, or does the information have to be built up in an other way?

My only solution that I have so far is to directly access the Database through a JDBC driver (rather than using the API) and do a JOIN on the tagsasset and tagsentry tables (which is in effect what tagsassets_tagsentries is). Is there a better way than doing this?

Many thanks.

EDIt

I'm using Liferay 5.2.3. Sorry for not responding or updating until now, I recieved no notifications about any responses! :)

Comment: It helps to know which version of Liferay you're using :)

Comment: @limburgie I'm using Liferay 5.2.3, and I've edited my post accordingly. However brandizzi has answered my question below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet that there is no such API because `tagsentries_tagsassets` is just a junction table. It is represented in the API as the lists of tags of an article *and* as the list of articles of a tag.

Generating a LAR should be the solution, although it is not. A better solution IMHO is to generate a dump of the original database and restore the dump in the other one. Note that the best way to do it is to generate a dump of the *entire* database - all tables and data - so you guarantee the consistency.

Is there a reason for not doing it? If so, explain your problem so we can explore it in more details.

Comment: Sorry I've only just realised you answered my question. Thank you. I couldn't do an entire dump because I was moving content from one Liferay instance to another, which already had other communities etc. I just needed the historical articles, tags, etc etc.